# How to Query ESRI Rest Service with SQL

Tags: sql, api, ms-access, gis, esri

Given a link to an ESRI rest service, like a feature layer, what is the SQL command or code to pull from that rest service?

More specifically, I would like to query an ESRI rest service with SQL and import it into an Access Database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if its a rest service, you should consume it using a request, not sql query. Please take a look at following Pages:
https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/query-a-feature-layer/
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the source of data published in ESRI rest services. if the source of the data is from SQL/Oracle database, then you may fetch the data from SQL query and import into Access database.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a tutorial on REST endpoints](http://mmdolbow.github.io/RESTendpts/index.html), specifically focusing on the Esri style. I hope the "Building Queries" section helps you. Essentially, if you can navigate to the "Query" form of the layer (should look [something like this](https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/4/query)), you can typically use basic SQL syntax in the "WHERE" box.

Then, for pulling into local data, I would suggest [this scraper python code](https://github.com/crackernutter/EsriRESTScraper). I don't think it'll pull into Access specifically but you might be able to modify it to do that.